# DeSerialize xml string and ignore the first element within root

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I've got this XML data in string, structure can be seen as follows:

```
  <Document>
     <Contents>
        <Content>
        ...
     <Contents>
  </Document>
```

So the structure is always like above, I made a class which exactly reflects the objects which will be identified as `<Content>`.

I wonder how I can deserialize the content in one go into a `List` of `Content` objects. Currently I try something as

```
XmlSerializer annotationSerializer = new XmlSerializer(
            typeof(List<Content>),
            new XmlRootAttribute("Document")
        );
```

Of course this will not work as the first found element will be contents, how do I work around this? Do I require a certain attribute on the `Content` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a root object here:

```
public class Document {
   public List<Content> Contents {get;} = new List<Content>();
}
```

Now deserialize a `Document` and read `.Contents`. There *are* some scenarios where you can bypass the root object, but... not here, not conveniently.

Comment: Allright, that's a pity, I really wanted to avoid having a "Document" class